# How to select nodes using bingo outpu table

Tags: cytoscape

I'm making enrichment analysis with Bingo app. When I select category in tabular output and click "select nodes" nothing happens.
Does anyone know how to fix it.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with Cytoscape 3.9.1 and java-11-openjdk-amd64 and Bingo 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The nodes are selected in the original network, not in the BiNGO network.  Also note that selecting the category doesn't actually enable the selection of nodes within that category.  You need to check the box at the far left, then you can use the select nodes button.

Comment: I've been doing just like you write. When I select original network, select category in BiNGO output and click Select nodes button the network "blink" but nothing is selected.